# Using apa6 document class, images won't appear

Tags: graphics, apa6

I'm using `\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}` to write my bachelor thesis, but my images won't appear. Is anyone familiar with this problem? The extensions are correct and it works in any other test file that I make. The problem appears to be with the document class.

The code I use:

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Large scale analysis of ChIP-seq data from KRAB zinc-finger proteins}
\shorttitle{APA style}

\author{Stijn F. Robben}
\affiliation{BSc Student Biomedical Sciences, UvA}

\rightheader{APA style}
\leftheader{Stijn F. Robben}

\begin{document}
\maketitle    

\section{Introduction}

\section{Materials \& Methods}

\includegraphics{histogram_znf134.pdf}

\bibliography{sample}

\clearpage
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{histogram_znf135.pdf}
  \end{center}
  \caption{Visualization}
  \label{fig:ar}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

What I get:

[image]

Comment: Welcome, you posted just a fragment. We cannot reproduce what you see. Please make the example complete, i.e. compilable.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I tried to edit it. Hope you'll be able to compile it now.

Comment: The abstract is missing its closing brace, apart from that, your example compiles fine and i see the image. Seeing a frame and the filename indicates that the `draft` option is activated. Please test your example (with the closing brace fixed), what do you get?

Comment: Everything compiles without any errors, but I still don't see the image. I indeed only see the frame and filename, not the image itself. Thank you for your help btw

Comment: Since this is a twocolumn document, you should specify lengths depending on `\linewidth`. On the other hand, using `apa6` for a bachelor thesis isn't the best idea to begin with. Maybe use a [minimal template](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports)?

Comment: You are probably right, but a solution for this problem would still be interesting for future use of apa6

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the option `draft` in the `\documentclass` line of your actual document?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. Also when I download the file, only the frame and the image name are shown...

Comment: Can you upload the `.log` file to a file hoster and link here?

Comment: What do you mean by .log? And what would be an appropriate file hoster to use?

Comment: The image I use can be found here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=27130170164771499322

Comment: You can try `\usepackage[final]{graphicx}`

Comment: I tried, but then I get the error: 'option clash for package graphicx'

Comment: Try to add `final` to the documentclass options.